# Get error when trying to log in by facebook through ios App

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I've integrated Facebook login SDK into my iOS project and try to get user's email address and so on.

But When I pressed facebook login Button through my app then this error shows
[image]

I know this kind of questions have been asked already. But I've not found any solution yet. Every year developers.facebook.com has been updated. So previous solution may not be worked. Any Help or suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the permission from the facebook developer console(developer to production mode)

[image: switch for production mode]
[image: provide privacy policy url of you project website]

or you can add testusers in facebook developer console for testing purpose(Roles > TestUser).